# Match a continuously repeated backreference in a given times and no more

Tags: python, regex

In a simplified case, I want to extract a repeated number(3 times) from input string, but only 3 times and no more.

```
#match a backreference(\d here) 2 more times
#11222(333)34445 get matched and consumed, 
#then the current position moves to 11222333^34445
In [3]: re.findall(r'(\d)\1{2}','1122233334445')
Out[3]: ['2', '3', '4']

#try to exclude 11222(333)34445 by setting a non-backreference(?!\1)
#as a negative lookahead assertion, it skips the match of 
#11222^(333)34445, but get captured in the next position
#112223^(333)4445
In [4]: re.findall(r'(\d)\1{2}(?!\1)','1122233334445')
Out[4]: ['2', '3', '4']

#backreference cannot go before the referenced group
In [5]: re.findall(r'(?!\1)(\d)\1{2}(?!\1)','1122233334445')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-a5837badf5bb> in <module>()
----> 1 re.findall(r'(?!\1)(\d)\1{2}(?!\1)','1122233334445')

/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    179 
    180     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 181     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    182 
    183 if sys.hexversion >= 0x02020000:

/usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc in _compile(*key)
    249         p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
    250     except error, v:
--> 251         raise error, v # invalid expression
    252     if not bypass_cache:
    253         if len(_cache) >= _MAXCACHE:

error: bogus escape: '\\1'
```

But what I expect is `['2','4']`.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to express by `(?!\1)` ? and what are you trying to match by the 3rd regex in general?

Comment: @alfasin: "3 digits not preceded nor followed by the same digit". The lookbehind fails since the capture has not yet been captured (and also, capture variables are not supported in lookbehinds anyway according to docs).

Comment: @Amadan I suspected that that was the intention - but I wanted him to figure it out by himself :)

Comment: @alfasin: Anyway, the docs say so, but for reasons I can't figure out, this works for me (Python 2.7.6): `re.findall(r'(\d)(?<!\1..)\1{2}(?!\1)','122333444455555666666')` gives `['3']` (and `['2', '4']` on OP's query). If backreferences worked, I would have expected `(?<!\1.)`.

Comment: Here's a workaround https://eval.in/400354

Comment: @hwnd That is brilliant. It consumes the unwanted matches and put them in a separated group.

Comment: @huazhihao hwnd's answer would fail if the input is `11222333344454`. It would print 2 and 4. But it has to print 2 only.

Comment: did you wan to check for continuous digits only?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I expect 11222333344454 to output 2 and 4.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, I mean yes.

Comment: @Amadan: The width of backreference, according to the pattern width analysis in `sre_parse.py`, is always 0 (which is wrong), so `..` pushes the start position of the lookbehind back 2 characters and gives the correct result.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Ah, that makes sense, thanks. Then still the question that remains is how reliable it is, given that it shouldn't work at all according to the docs.

Comment: @Amadan: I wouldn't use it at all for forward compatibility reason. It's clearly a bug, and we don't want a surprise breakage in the future. Using it for non-production code or throw away script is fine, though.

Comment: @Amadan: I'm not sure if the bug is fixed, but it seems the source code of `getwidth` in sre_parse is changed in 3.5, which affects how width of backreference is calculated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need backreference in a lookbehind to find the borders between different digits, before matching the sequence without consuming which are little supported among the regex flavors. Something like `(\d)(?<!\1.)\1{2}(?!\1)` [works in .NET](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5cd)(%3f%3c!%5c1.)%5c1%7b2%7d(%3f!%5c1)&i=112223333444544) but [not in Python obviously](https://regex101.com/r/cM3dG6/1).

An idea is to use [The Great Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#nocontext) like @hwnd commented. This is also of great performance with the downside of getting some dispensable elements. Another idea to find the boundary between two different digits as a requirement would be to capture inside a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?:^|(?<=(\d))(?!\1))(\d)\2{2}(?!\2)
```

- `(?:^|(?<=(\d))(?!\1))` The part with lookbehind for finding boundaries between different digits.
- `(\d)\2{2}(?!\2)` 2nd capture-group captures a digit to `\2`. Followed by the same digit at least 2x - using a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for not being followed by the same digit again.

This should give accurate matches but requires more steps for the parser. See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hL4qQ0/5).

Comment: Your regex `(?<=(\d)|^)(?!\1)(\d)(?=\2{2}(?!\2))` doesn't compile in Python 2.7.8, 3.2.5 and 3.4.3

Comment: @nhahtdh can you check updated answer, would that work for you?

Comment: @Jonny5: It's now a working solution. Just a note: you don't need positive look-ahead wrapper `(?=\2{2}(?!\2))`, just `\2{2}(?!\2)` is OK. `findall` only return the captured text if the pattern has capturing groups. And Python code: `print [i[1] for i in re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<=(\d)))(?!\1)(\d)(?=\2{2}(?!\2))', input)]`

Comment: @nhahtdh thanks for your comment. Yes I already noted that in the first version but updated the pattern accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
x="1122233334445"
print [j for i,j in re.findall(r"(\d)\1{3,}|(\d)\2{2}",x) if not i]
```

Try this.This will give `['2', '4']`

Comment: It works. Your answer is very like hwnd 's comment. I am still glad to give a +1.

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(\d)\1{2}', re.sub(r'(\d)\1{3,}', '',  '1122233334445'))
['2', '4']
```

Remove all digits which repeated more than 3 time, then find those repeated for exactly 3 times.

Comment: This is not the case.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to what's wrong with @piglei's answer?

Comment: @huazhihao This may not be very brilliant answer, but I'm pretty sure it fixes your problem.

Comment: What I expect is a working regex pattern, not a manipulated input string to meet the pattern.

Comment: @huazhihao Then you should write this in your question.